# jquery autocomplete lable value undefined in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to display some cities in autocomplete using jquery and when any one selects the city then set the destination id to hidden field . i am using web service to get data for ajax call .

here is my webservice method :

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<BALDestinations> AuotExtenderDestination(string destinationname)
    {
        DataSet ds=objDestination.GetDestination(destinationname);
        List<BALDestinations> result = new List<BALDestinations>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            BALDestinations b = new BALDestinations();
            b.City = dr["City"].ToString();
            b.DestinationId = dr["DestinationId"].ToString();
            result.Add(b);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and this is the code of my  jquery autocomplete textbox extender

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            alert($("#hiddenAllowSearch").val());
        });
    });  
    function SearchText() {
        $(".txtdest").autocomplete({
            //   source: $local_source,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/AuotExtenderDestination",
                    data: "{'destinationname':'" + $('.txtdest').val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                      response(data.d);                      
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $(".txtdest").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(".txtdest").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#hiddenAllowSearch").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
    } 
</script>
```

undefined appear in text box when we type anything there

Comment: Hi in my opinion I think you should have left the code in your question as you had it originally. Anyone looking at the question now won't see how you had written the code originally and thus won't be able to see the difference and learn from Cory's answer. I was staring at your code for several minutes thinking there was nothing wrong with it until I realised you'd updated it.

Comment: @Bruen sorry for that , i have roll back my edit and now question is same as its original one . and i just made edit because after cory answer i am facing an issue . you can check cory and my conversation on comments about this

Comment: No problem at all, it's a good question and I think a lot of people including myself get tripped up with that response object.

Comment: @Bruen now i am trying to add city,state/province.country  name to label instead of single city name and one more thing i check at least 20 amswers realted to this on S.O. but none of them is clear to me . might be i am missing something or i can say some where i find the web service or some where i find the ajax call but both things are no where ....so i think its help a lot of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the properties on the class that you are returning from your web service aren't `label`, and `value`, then the jQuery Autocomplete code will be trying to read values from non-existent properties, and thus your `undefined` issue arises.

If you don't want to change your class properties, you can set up the autocomplete to look at your actual property names. Instead of just calling `response(data.d)`, you can map your class properties to `label` and `value` manually before sending it through the `response` function:

```
response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
    return { 
        label: item.City, 
        value: item.DestinationId
    };
}));
```

Comment: Just `label` and `value`. AFAIK, `id` doesn't do anything special in jQueryUI autocomplete.

Comment: @Cory sir i am able to get label like city name but in alert of alert($("#hiddenAllowSearch").val());
 its still show city name but i want destinationId

Comment: @Cory thanx its problem is that if they dont found the exact value part then jquery use the label as value and in my case problem is only DestinationID vs DestinationId  thanks again its done

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Sorry about that typo, I fixed it in the example (DestinationID vs. DestinationId).

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: You're correct. Looks like I did some customization -- I throw the `id` in the hidden input, the `label` in the drop-down search results, and `value` in the search textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add city, state/province, and country names to the label instead of a single city name, then you could extend your code and add the extra values to a custom object:

Service:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    BALDestinations b = new BALDestinations();
    b.City = dr["City"].ToString();
    b.DestinationId = dr["DestinationId"].ToString();
    b.State = dr["State"].ToString();
    b.Province = dr["Province"].ToString();
    b.Country = dr["Country"].ToString();

    result.Add(b);
}
```

Ajax `success` callback:

```
response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

    // return custom object
    var resultList = { 
        label: item.City + ", " + item.State + ", " +
               item.Province + "' " + item.Country, 
        value: item.DestinationId,

        // Alternatively, you can return the properties in
        // this object and display them via _renderItem     
        state: item.State, 
        province: item.Province, 
        country: item.Country 
    };

    return resultList;
}));
```

To display the state, province, and country in the autocomplete list, overwrite `_renderItem`:

```
$(".txtdest").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // etc.
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a><strong>" + item.value + "</strong><br>" + item.state +
            " PROVINCE: " + item.province + " COUNTRY: " + item.country + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```